# Time complexity of the following code snippet

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

### Question

Time complexity of the following code snippet -:

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
      sum++;
```

#### My approach

> $\text{sum}$ is running exactly $j$ times for each each $k$

As an example , if i take

$i=1 \Rightarrow \text{j will run 1 time} \Rightarrow \text{sum will run}\,\, 1\,\, \text{time} $

$i=2 \Rightarrow \text{j will run 4 time}$ i.e for $j=0,1,2,3$

Sum will be execute total of $0+1+2+3$

$i=n \Rightarrow \text{j will run } n^{2}$ time i.e for $j=0,1,2,3,...n^2$
sum will be executed

$1+2+3+..n^2 \approx n^4$

then it should be $O(n^4)$

Am i right?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i^2} \sum_{k=1}^j 1&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i^2} j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i^2}{2}(i^2+1)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i^4+i^2}{2}\\
&= \Theta(n^5)
\end{align}

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Comment: sir please have a look here , i am unable to genralize eqtn like you in this qstn https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499375/time-complexity-for-the-given-code?noredirect=1#comment5162491_2499375

Answer (score 1):

You can write the number of iterations as $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i^2-1} j$, which is $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Theta(i^4)$, which is $\Theta(n^5)$.

Comment: thanks a lot :)